# Make it so that the end user is responsible for their actions

Tags: responsibility, end-user

I have a program that can find sites that are exploitable and exploit them, I posted this on my Github and people started using it. I recently have been contacted by an owner of one of the websites (my email address is there for troubleshooting issues) who was extremely upset about their website being exploited, and found using my tool.

Is there a license, thing to say (disclaimer), or something I can do to make it so that when someone uses my tool, if they exploit something, it doesn't fall back on me?

I'm thinking that since I created the tool, it would come back to haunt me ultimately, even though I am not able to control others actions. Any help with this would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a standard MIT license covers that:
[link](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)
Read the last part.